# Mono for Android: Map Balloons for Mono

Tags: android, mono, annotations, android-mapview, xamarin.android

I'm looking for a `C#` version of the https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

This project mimics the `iOS MapAnnotions` objects allowing for easier placing of information on pins for maps.

Comment: Have you considered porting the 4 files needed to get this working to C#? It would not take long to do...

Comment: Has anyone had any luck porting over the files to mono? I'm looking for this exact same thing and it would be awesome if someone had already taken the time to do this.

Comment: Refer to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519083/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-use-java-code-in-mono-for-android/12584645#12584645), I've ported over one of the classes into c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not going to be as relevant in a couple of weeks, but there is a Binding project for android-mapviewballoons on github : https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/AndroidMapViewBalloons.

HTH.